# Cannot import framework after converting project from ObjC to Swift - 'No such module'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, data-conversion

I'm a newbie coder, re-using an app design originally coded in ObjC. The app is camera-based and compiles and runs fine in XCode 9.2 running an image recognition service against a 3rd party's cloud servers.

I converted the app using Swiftify from ObjC to Swift and on attempting to build it now throws a Swift Compiler error and states that the 3rd party framework isn't there (specifically, Cannot import framework after converting project from ObjC to Swift - 'No such module XXXXSDK'.

I have checked the path to the framework is correct and it is located and described correctly.

1. Is this error due to the location of the framework, or could it be the format of the framework as well?
2. Any tips on how I identify the cause and resolve it? (rebuilding the framework is not an option for me as it is provided by a 3rd party)

Comment: There are 17 headers in the Headers folder of the framework. I attempted to add them individually to my bridging header - that didn't work as the error "no such file" persists for any of the headers added.

Comment: I've then deleted the Bridging Header and built a new one, as I began to get errors whereby the bridging header could not be found and the PCH would not process either. I am back to square one at this point; Swift Compiler error - no such module, with my bridging header in place but no reference to the framework in it.